# "igraph.plot" and "edge.lty" in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have organized my network data in a datasheet (header= TRUE), such as:

n  V1  V2 Year  Influence        Dialogic

1  A    B 1995 Coercitive      Antagonism

2  C    D 1995 Normative      Complementarity

3  E F 1995 Cultural       Competition

...

As way to add attributes for my edges in igraph:

```
Coercitive <- "red", 
Normative <- "yellow",
Cultural <- "green"
```

and

```
Antagonism <- 1, 
Complementarity <- 2,
Competition <- 3
```

But, when I plot it, I have just the color attributes and receive an error message for the line type, such as: "Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : invalid line type"

my plot script is simple:

```
plot(a, layout= layout.auto(a), vertex.color= "black", vertex.label.color=NULL, vertex.frame.color= "black", vertex.label.font= 1, vertex.label.cex= .75, vertex.label= V(a)$name, vertex.shape="circle", vertex.size= 2, vertex.size2= NULL, vertex.label.dist= -.25, edge.label= NULL, edge.label.color= NULL, vertex.label.degree= -pi/4, edge.arrow.size= 0.5, edge.loop.angle= 0.5, edge.arrow.width= 0.25, edge.curved= seq(-.5, .5, length = ecount(a)), edge.color= Influence, edge.lty= Dialogic)
```

As you can see, I used the same script for "Influence" (that works fine), and Dialogic (which didn't work).

Someone could figure out how to kill this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I just added before plotting the following script:

```
edge.lty= E(a)$lty <- E(a)$Dialogic
```

and plotted in the easy way:

```
plot(a, layout= layout.auto(a), vertex.color= "black", vertex.label.color=NULL, vertex.frame.color= "black", vertex.label.font= 1, vertex.label.cex= .75, vertex.label= V(a)$name, vertex.shape="circle", vertex.size= 2, vertex.size2= NULL, vertex.label.dist= -.25, edge.label= NULL, edge.label.color= NULL, vertex.label.degree= -pi/4, edge.arrow.size= 0.5, edge.loop.angle= 0.5, edge.arrow.width= 0.25, edge.curved= seq(-.5, .5, length = ecount(a)), edge.color= Influence, edge.lty= E(a))
```

and that is it: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's better than that, it is already there, in the attributes. So, it is just a case of writing:

```
edge.lty= E(a)
```

into the plot script.